# Chinese Remainder Theorem with with non-pairwise coprime moduli

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

I have a system of congruences:
$$
x\equiv 1\pmod 2 \\
x\equiv 2\pmod 3 \\
x\equiv 3\pmod 4 \\
x\equiv 4\pmod 5 \\
x\equiv 5\pmod 6 \\
x\equiv 0\pmod 7
$$

2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 are non-pairwise coprime, so i can't use Chinese Reminder Theorem in this case.

$x\equiv 3\pmod 4$ yields $x\equiv 1\pmod 2$ so i can just drop 3-rd equation from the system.

Using this principle i got new system:

$$
x\equiv 1\pmod 2 \\
x\equiv 2\pmod 3 \\
x\equiv 0\pmod 7 \\
$$

Solving this system o got the answer: $497 + 42k$, which is actually wrong.

Right answer i can get here: http://maciejkus.com/chinese_remainder/ , which is: $119 + 420k$

How can i solve this system right?

Comment: You cannot drop third, you can only drop first and second equation.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't $x\equiv 6\pmod{7}$?

Comment: $497+42k$ is the solution of the system with the $3$ equations. Better would be the representation $35+42k$.

Comment: Considering also the equation with the $mod\ 5$, we get $119+120k$ and $119$ solves the complete system already. So, we have to find the period. It is $lcm(2,3,4,5,6,7)=420$. So, the solution of the complete system is $119+420k$.

Comment: @kingW3, i am sure it's $x\equiv 0\pmod 7$

Comment: It is enough to consider the equations with the moduli $3,4,5,7$ because the modulo-$4$-equation covers the modulo-$2$-equation and therefore (together wit the modulo-$3$-equation) also the modulo-$6$-equation. And now, you have pairwise coprime moduli.

Comment: I think i have to add $x\equiv 4\pmod 5$ equation to the new system too.

Comment: Did you try solving for $x+1$ and than finding $x$ from it?

Comment: Adding the equation with moduli 5 i got solution: $-91+210k$

Comment: **Exact Dupe** of  [Solve $x\equiv 1\pmod2$, $x\equiv 2\pmod3$, $x\equiv 3\pmod4$, $x\equiv 4\pmod5$, $x\equiv 5\pmod6$ and $x\equiv 0\pmod7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394635/solve-x-equiv-1-pmod2-x-equiv-2-pmod3-x-equiv-3-pmod4-x-equiv-4-pmod5)

Answer (score 1):

$$
x\equiv 1\pmod 2 \\
x\equiv 2\pmod 3 \\
x\equiv 3\pmod 4 \\
x\equiv 4\pmod 5 \\
x\equiv 5\pmod 6 \\
x\equiv 0\pmod 7
$$

$x\equiv 5\pmod 6$ if and only if $x\equiv 1\pmod 2$ and $x\equiv 2\pmod 3$. and both conditions are already on the list. This leaves us with

$$
x\equiv 1\pmod 2 \\
x\equiv 2\pmod 3 \\
x\equiv 3\pmod 4 \\
x\equiv 4\pmod 5 \\
x\equiv 0\pmod 7
$$

$x\equiv 3\pmod 4$ implies that $x\equiv 1\pmod 2$ but not vice-versa. So we keep the first and remove the second.

$$
x\equiv 2\pmod 3 \\
x\equiv 3\pmod 4 \\
x\equiv 4\pmod 5 \\
x\equiv 0\pmod 7
$$

The solution is $x = 119$