# Solve $x\equiv 1\pmod2$, $x\equiv 2\pmod3$, $x\equiv 3\pmod4$, $x\equiv 4\pmod5$, $x\equiv 5\pmod6$ and $x\equiv 0\pmod7$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

$$\begin{align*}
x&\equiv 1\pmod2\\
x&\equiv 2\pmod3\\
x&\equiv 3\pmod4\\
x& \equiv 4\pmod5\\
x&\equiv 5\pmod6\\
x&\equiv 0\pmod7\\
\end{align*}$$

So the solution says we can eliminate $x\equiv 5(\bmod6)$ because the first two cases cover it, but I don't really know how it does. How do we solve it in cases like this where the moduli are not mutually relatively prime.

Comment: Well, if $x\equiv 5\pmod6$, then $x=6k+5$. Now what is the remainder of $x$ modulo 2? or modulo 3? can you tell?

Comment: Hint:  It's clearer if you rewrite the first five congruences as, equivalently, $x\equiv -1\pmod {2,3,4,5,6}$.

Comment: $x=6k+5=2(3k+2)+1 \equiv 1(mod2)$. $x=6k+5=3(2k+2)-1\equiv 2(mod3)$. I see that's interesting.

Comment: Well, that's what you do when the moduli aren't coprime. You split them into prime powers and work with those.

Answer (score 2):

Since  $\,m_i-1\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}\pmod{\!m_i}\,$ we can apply $ $ [CCRT = $\rm\color{#c00}{constant}$ case optimization of CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2006919/242)

$\qquad\qquad\ \ \ \begin{align} x &\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}\!\!\!\pmod{\!m_1}\\
&\ \ \vdots\\
x &\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}\!\!\!\pmod{\!m_k}\end{align}
\!\iff\ x\equiv \color{#c00}{-1}\pmod{\!{\rm lcm}\{m_1,\ldots,m_k)}$

$\ \ \ \ \  \text{or, without CRT:}\ \ \ {\rm  all}\ \  m_i \mid x+1 \iff {\rm lcm}\{{\rm all}\ m_i\}\mid x+1$

The latter equivalence is by the [Universal Property of LCM](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2322544/242) (= *definition* of LCM  in general)

Therefore $\, x\equiv -1\pmod{2,3,4,5,6}\iff x\equiv\color{#0a0}{-1}\pmod{\color{#0a0}{\!60} = {\rm lcm}(2,3,4,5,6})$

So $\bmod 7\!:\,\ 0\equiv x\equiv \color{#0a0}{60k-1}\equiv 4k-1\iff 4k\equiv 1\equiv 8\iff k\equiv 2\iff \color{#90f}{k = 2\!+\!7n}$

Combining yields $\ x = 60\color{#90f}k-1 = 60(\color{#90f}{2\!+\!7n})-1 = 119 + 420n$

**Remark** $ $ To compute the lcm we can either use [prime factorizations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3247013/242) or else use [distributivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1163840/242) and *factor deletion:* $\,[a,ab,c,\ldots] = [ab,c,\ldots]\,$ since $\,a,ab\mid m\iff ab\mid m.\,$ Applied to OP

$$[\color{#0a0}2,\color{#c00}3,\color{#0a0}4,5,\color{#c00}6] = [4,5,6] = [5,2[2,3]] = [5,12] = 60\qquad $$

[since](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/194978/242) $\,[a,b] = ab\ $ for $a,b$ coprime (we also used [associativity and commutativity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/254996/242) of lcm).

Generally, for congruence systems with noncoprime moduli we can factor the moduli to split the congruences into an equivalent system with pair-coprime modulu (e.g distinct prime powers) e.g [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3076446/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2411033/242) or we can solve it $2$ congruences at a time while cancelling common moduli factors.

---

[More generally](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3281011/242) this idea works for linearly related values & moduli:  $ $  if $\,(a,b) = 1\,$ then

$$\left\{\,x\equiv d\!-\!ck\!\!\!\pmod{b\!-\!ak}\,\right\}_{k=0}^{n}\!\!\iff\! x\equiv \dfrac{ad\!-\!bc}a\!\!\!\pmod{{\rm lcm}\{b\!-\!ak\}_{k=0}^n}\quad  \   $$

$ $ e.g.  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3395019/242) $\,\ \underbrace{\left\{\,x \equiv 3-k\pmod{7-k}\,\right\}_{k=0}^2}_{\textstyle{x\equiv 3,2,1\pmod{\!7,6,5}}}\!\!\iff\!  x\equiv \dfrac{1(3)-7(1)}1\equiv -4\pmod{210}$

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can eliminate it indeed

- $x\equiv 1 \pmod 2 \implies x=2k+1$
- $x\equiv 2 \pmod 3 \implies 2k+1\equiv 2 \pmod 3\implies k\equiv 2  \pmod 3\implies k=3h+2$

that is

$$x=6k+5 \implies x\equiv 5\pmod 6$$

Note that we can also eliminate $x\equiv 1 \pmod 2$ since we have that $x\equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Then we can use [**CRT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to solve the system:

- $x\equiv 2 \pmod 3$
- $x\equiv 3 \pmod 4$
- $x\equiv 4 \pmod 5$
- $x\equiv 0 \pmod 7$

Comment: Would it be better to elimate $x\equiv 3(mod4)$ because we eliminate $5(mod6)$ because of $1(mod2)$?

Comment: We can't eliminate $x\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ since $x\equiv 1 \pmod 2 \not \Rightarrow x\equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the reduced equations , we get

$$ \color{ red} {x = 3k+2 \quad \quad {\text(1)}}$$

Substituting it into the next gives us :

$$\color {#F0A}{3k+2\equiv 3\mod 4 \implies  k \equiv 3 \mod 4 \implies k = 4j +3 \quad \quad \text { (2)}}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get :

$$\color{ blue}{x = 12j + 11}$$

Substituting it into the next gives us :
$$\color {#50F}{12j +11 \equiv 4 \mod 5 \implies j\equiv 4 \mod 5 \implies j = 5l +4 \quad \quad \text { (3)}}$$

From $(1)$ and $(3)$ we get :
$$\color{ green}{x = 60l +59 \quad \quad \text{ (4)}}$$

And finally from the last equation , we get :

$$\color {orange}{60l +59 \equiv 0 \mod 7 \implies l \equiv1 \mod 7 \implies l = 7y+1 \quad \quad \text{ (5)} }$$

And we get :

$$\boxed{\color{navy}{x = 60 (7y+1) +59 \implies x = 420y + 119}}$$

Hence all values of form $420y + 119$ is the solution starting from $119,539...$

Answer (score 0):

Because of the special case
$$x\equiv -1\pmod {2,3,4,5,6}$$
we have a shortcut for handling these.
$$x+1\equiv 0\pmod {2,3,4,5,6}$$
It is way easier to work with $x+1$ here.
This gives us
$$x+1 \equiv 0 \pmod {LCM(2,3,4,5,6)=60}$$

Now we need to incorporate
$$x+1 \equiv 1 \pmod 7 $$
Which is easy, as $7$ is prime. List out the first 6 multiples of $60$.

$$\begin{align}
1 \cdot 60 \equiv 4 \pmod 7 \\\\
2 \cdot 60 \equiv \color{red}1 \pmod 7 \\\\
3 \cdot 60 \equiv 5 \pmod 7 \\\\
4 \cdot 60 \equiv 2 \pmod 7 \\\\
5 \cdot 60 \equiv 6 \pmod 7 \\\\
6 \cdot 60 \equiv 3 \pmod 7 \\\\
\end{align}$$

So our answer is
$$ x +1 \equiv 2 \cdot 60 \pmod{ 7 \cdot 60}$$
or
$$ x \equiv 2 \cdot 60 -1 \pmod {7 \cdot 60}$$